# hidden circular text at certain width jQuery shows on load when should be hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im using jQuery to hide some circular text below 760px window width. It is working correctly, but if you load the page below 760px width, the text is displayed, then it is hidden again when the browser is resized. Im sure there is a very straight forward solution to this but I dont know what it is.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(this).width() < 760) {
    $('.circular-text').hide();
  } else {
    $('.circular-text').show();
    }
});

const text = document.querySelector(".circular-text .contact-text")
const rotate = new CircleType(text).radius(65)
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  text.style.transform=`rotate(${window.scrollY * 0.15}deg)`
});
```

```css
.circular-text{
display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 70px;
    z-index: 999999;
}

.contact-text{
    font-family: "Alliance No 2";
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fb4d98;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.3.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-container">  
        <div class="circular-text">
            <p class="contact-text">contact us • contact us • contact us •</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is only executed when you resize the window.

Instead, move it into a function and call it on page load, then attach it to the window `resize` event listener.

```js
function checkWidth() {
  if ($(this).width() < 760) {
    $('.circular-text').hide();
  } else {
    $('.circular-text').show();
  }
}
checkWidth();

$(window).resize(checkWidth);

const text = document.querySelector(".circular-text .contact-text")
const rotate = new CircleType(text).radius(65)
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  text.style.transform = `rotate(${window.scrollY * 0.15}deg)`
});
```

```css
.circular-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 70px;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.contact-text {
  font-family: "Alliance No 2";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fb4d98;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.3.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-container">
  <div class="circular-text">
    <p class="contact-text">contact us • contact us • contact us •</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To fix the fading out issue, just add an `if` statement to check whether the width is greater than 760px:

```js
function checkWidth() {
  if ($(this).width() < 760) {
    $('.circular-text').hide();
  } else {
    $('.circular-text').show();
  }
}
checkWidth();

$(window).resize(checkWidth);

const text = document.querySelector(".circular-text .contact-text")
const rotate = new CircleType(text).radius(65)
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  text.style.transform = `rotate(${window.scrollY * 0.15}deg)`
});

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var distanceFromBottom = Math.floor($(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop() - $(window).height());
  if (distanceFromBottom < 350) {
    $('#contact-fixed').fadeOut();
    if ($(this).width() > 760) {
      $('.circular-text').fadeOut();
    }
  } else {
    $('#contact-fixed').fadeIn();
    if ($(this).width() > 760) {
      $('.circular-text').fadeIn();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.circular-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 69px;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.contact-text {
  font-family: "Alliance No 2";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fb4d98;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.3.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-container">
  <div class="circular-text">
    <p class="contact-text">contact us • contact us • contact us •</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To fix the problem with the library improperly re-rendering the text on resize, we can re-render it programmatically in the `resize` event listener.

#### Final Result:

```js
const text = document.querySelector(".circular-text .contact-text")

function checkWidth() {
  const rotate = new CircleType(text).radius(65)
  if ($(this).width() < 760) {
    $('.circular-text').hide();
  } else {
    $('.circular-text').show();
  }
}
checkWidth();

$(window).resize(checkWidth);



window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  text.style.transform = `rotate(${window.scrollY * 0.15}deg)`
});

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var distanceFromBottom = Math.floor($(document).height() - $(document).scrollTop() - $(window).height());
  if (distanceFromBottom < 350) {
    $('#contact-fixed').fadeOut();
    if ($(this).width() > 760) {
      $('.circular-text').fadeOut();
    }
  } else {
    $('#contact-fixed').fadeIn();
    if ($(this).width() > 760) {
      $('.circular-text').fadeIn();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.circular-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 69px;
  z-index: 999999;
}

.contact-text {
  font-family: "Alliance No 2";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fb4d98;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.3.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-container">
  <div class="circular-text">
    <p class="contact-text">contact us • contact us • contact us •</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working thanks, but another piece of jQuery that fades the text when you are 350px from the bottom of the page is interfering with it and making it appear below 760px if you scroll the mouse, and I need both. Is it possible to combine the code so that the text is hidden below 760 always, and fades above 760 when you reach 350px from the bottom of the page? [Here](https://codepen.io/gjjr/pen/bGWxWZd) is a codepen with all of the code.

Comment: @gjjr Sure, no problem. I'll take a look at the codepen and update my answer.

Comment: Perfect thanks! If you resize the browser below 760, you will see the text disappear as required, but then if you scroll down it will reappear, so I need it to be always hidden below 760. Thanks!

Comment: @gjjr I've updated my answer to include the working code (incorporated into your codepen).

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, I still need the element '#contact-fixed' to show below and above 760.

Comment: @gjjr Sorry, what do you mean? `#contact-fixed` is shown regardless of width. Did you mean you want to show it even when the user scrolls past 350px?

Comment: In your code above youve set an if statement on the scroll behaviour `$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).width() > 760) {` Doesnt that mean that the fade on scroll will only work above 760? I need the fade on scroll to work on all browser sizes for '#contact-fixed' , hope im making sense.

Comment: Thats it thanks! BUT now im back to square one with my original issue when trying to just hide the element below 760 with CSS. If you run your code snippet above look at how the text looks. This is the same thing that happens when I hide it with CSS. On my site this happens when you load the page with the browser below 760, then resize it up...any idea whats happening?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235632/discussion-between-spectric-and-gjjr).

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a particular reason for doing this in jQuery I recommend using css to do this instead

```
@media screen and (max-width:759px) {
  .circular-text { display:none; }
}
```

Comment: Yes I was using CSS to achieve this, but for some reason if you loaded the page in mobile view, then resized the browser to laptop/desktop view, there were issues with the text being tiny and in the wrong place.